# Set "Terminal.app' to administer the computer

Tags: terminal

Every time I apply command `at`, there prompt a admin confirm window

```
$ echo "open non-technical.pdf" | at now + 1 minute
job 28 at Wed Oct 31 10:23:00 2018
```

How could I set ok as default

[image]